# Problema com PHPMailer no envio de e-mails

Tags: php, linux, servidor, phpmailer, smtp

Estou tendo problemas em um projeto que utiliza PHPMailer, o mesmo funcionava normalmente, porém agora está dando problema de Connection Timeout no site, entretanto quando executo o script via terminal o mesmo funciona perfeitamente.

Itens que já verifiquei:

- Credenciais de acesso;
- OpenSSL do servidor;
- Versão do php.ini carregada pelo browser x terminal;
- Debuguei o código e o problema aparente está na classe Send do phpmailer todo o resto do script funciona perfeitamente.

Alguém com o mesmo problema?

```
    <?php
try{

   require 'vendors/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
   require 'vendors/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
   require 'vendors/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';

$layout = "teste servidor antigo";

$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();// create a new object

$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = "mail.swoosh.com.br";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->Username = "meuemail@teste.com.br";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->SetFrom("meuemail@teste.com.br");
$mail->Subject = "Assunto";
$mail->Body = $layout ;
 $mail->AddAddress("teste33@gmail.com");
$mail->AddAddress("testen@gmail.com");
$mail->AddAddress("teste2@gmail.com");
 if(!$mail->Send()) {  
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
 }
}catch(Exception $e){
   print_r($e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa verificar o tempo necessário para fazer o envio de e-mail. Por padrão o PHP define (no PHP.ini) 30 segundos, caso passe esse tempo, o servidor corta a conexão com o cliente, liberando o servidor para novas conexões.

Você pode alterar esse tempo através do comando abaixo:

> set_time_limit($segundos);

Ficando assim:

```
<?php
try{

   require 'vendors/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
   require 'vendors/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
   require 'vendors/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';

$layout = "teste servidor antigo";
set_time_limit(50);
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();// create a new object

$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = "mail.swoosh.com.br";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->Username = "meuemail@teste.com.br";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->SetFrom("meuemail@teste.com.br");
$mail->Subject = "Assunto";
$mail->Body = $layout ;
 $mail->AddAddress("teste33@gmail.com");
$mail->AddAddress("testen@gmail.com");
$mail->AddAddress("teste2@gmail.com");
 if(!$mail->Send()) {  
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
 }
}catch(Exception $e){
   print_r($e);
}
```

Ou você pode fazer uma configuração definitiva para todo o site através do parâmetro  **max_execution_time** em php.ini.

O problema da segunda alternativa é que ela é válida para todo o site, podendo gerar um gargalo no atendimento de novas requisições.

Comment: Francisco o problema é que quando executo esse mesmo script no terminal, ele roda rapidamente não demora para disparar o e-mail

Comment: Podem haver dois problemas, um é de DNS como descrito [aqui] (https://techleader.pro/a/372-Fixing-slow-performance-of-sending-mail-from-PHP-via-Sendmail), porém nesse site [aqui] (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Sending-to-lists#maximising-performance) recomenda o envio para localhost e verificação do cache do DNS. 

Talvez o desempenho por linha de comando seja maior, devido a não utilização do php.ini (pelo que entendi vc testou com o mesmo php.ini do apache). Outra coisa que podemos observar é o desempenho em ambientes windows ser bem inferior aos do ambiente linux.

Comment: Obrigado pessoal, de fato acabei usando uma solução via terminal, armazenei os dados em uma tabela do banco de dados e na sequência um script que captura esses dados e monta o e-mail. O ambiente é Linux de fato é uma coisa bem intrigante